# missing positional argument on decorator

Tags: python, python-decorators

I have a problem in my project, when i started to compile. I got the error that the decorator is missing the positional argument.

```
def decorator(self,func):
    def decorate_it(*args,**kwargs):
        for ast in range(0,10):
            if ast==0 or ast==9:
                print("*"*10)
            elif ast==len(list(range(0,10)))//2:
                print("*  "+func()+"  *")
            else:
                print("*"+" "*(len(list(range(0,10)))-2)+"*")
@decorator
def selectTransaction(self,instc):
#instc=user/instance_user 
    while True:
        inputTransc=input("""
        What the transaction do you want ?
        (A)Withdraw money
        (B)Transfer
        (C)Check cash
        (D)E-money payment
        (E)cancel\n
        """)
        if inputTransc.upper()=="A" or inputTransc.upper()=="B":
            self.__script.write("{} is choosing \"Withdraw money\"\n".format(instc)) if inputTransc.upper(instc)=="A" else self.__script.write("{} is choosing \"Transfer\"\n".format(instc))
            return self.Withdrawmoney() if inputTransc.upper()=="A" else self.Transfer()
        elif inputTransc.upper()=="C" or inputTransc.upper()=="D":
            self.__script.write("{} is choosing \"Check cash\"\n".format(instc)) if inputTransc.upper(instc)=="B" else self.__script.write("{} is choosing \"emoney payment\"\n".format(instc))
            return self.CheckUserMoney() if inputTransc.upper()=="C" else self.emoneyPayment()
        elif inputTransc.upper()=="E":
            self.__script.write("{} is choosing \"cancel\"\n".format(instc))
            self.condATM=[False,True]
        else:
            pass
```

I keep getting the error

TypeError: decorator() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`def decorator(self,func)` should just be `def decorator(func)`. `decorator` should be moved out of the class your functions are defined in. Especially since it doesn't even use `self`.